# Assign values randomly using another table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-update

Essentially I have a table that looks something like

```
|     Email       |       FullName       |     FirstName       |       LastName    |   gender |
|     Email1      |       FullName1      |     FirstName1      |      LastName1    |    M     |
|     Email2      |       FullName2      |     FirstName2      |      LastName2    |    M     |
|     Email3      |       FullName3      |      FirstName3     |      LastName3    |    F     |
...
|   Email150000   |    FullName150000     | FirstName150000    | LastName150000    |    F     |
```

And another table that is just a bunch of random fullnames and gender that looks something like:

```
|    Fullname       |     gender     |
|   John Smith      |      M         |
|    Jane Doe       |      F         |
|    Kate Johnson   |      F         |
....
|    James Jones    |      M         |
```

I want to set the fullname in the large table of 150000 using names randomly selected from the random names table based on gender.

I have tried to use several of the solutions offered in other similar questions but the result is always the same: fullname is populated with the same name for males and for females.

I have tried using Case statements based on gender
I have tried a while loop and looping through the whole table which does not work and takes forever
I have attempted a cross apply

Can someone please help?

Comment: Please provide the second table and also the column names, so we can write a query with the exact column names to answer your question properly.

Comment: @MateenArif added the second table information in. Thanks for any help you can provide!